# Debris "is" or "are" called toxins

Tags: nouns, syntactic-analysis

"Debris are called toxins."

In this sentence, should I use "is" or "are"? I understand "debris" is an uncountable noun, so normally I would use "is". But I am referring to different kinds of debris. Toxins are referring to a collection of debris. So is "are" the correct way?

Or should I reformat this sentence?

Comment: I've only ever known "*debris **is/was***"

Comment: *Debris* is a singular, non-count noun. So you have to say things like *pieces of debris*, *kinds of debris* etc.

Comment: Whether or not you use a plural verb, you need to put *The* before *debris*.

Comment: It seems odd to me that you are equating debris and toxins, regardless.  You might want to check their definitions.

Comment: And why do you say "the debris are *called* toxins." Why not "the debris are toxins"? Or "the debris consists of toxins"? Or maybe just "the debris is toxic"? Why mention what it's called rather than what it is? Are they called toxins without actually being toxins?

Comment: @peterShor The text where this is written is to explain a certain process. To explain this process, I need to inform the reader what they are called.

Comment: @HotLicks I found debris might not be the right word indeed. This text was a translation of a Dutch text. But I might use Pollution instead of debris. The bad thing is, this text is to explain a certain process and I don't want to cause any misunderstanding.

Comment: There's a big difference between *debris* (the stuff that is left over after something is destroyed, or after some ) and *pollution* (contaminants).

Comment: In this text we're reffering to bacteria and feces, a collections of things that shouldn't be there. What would you suggest? I found that toxins should be replaced with slag. reffering to a harmful slimelayer in the colon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have only heard "debris is/was" and if there are many, use "pieces/piles of debris are/were".

From [ncsu.edu](https://www.ncsu.edu/ncsu/grammar/Nouns3.html) (styling mine)

> *Debris* doesn't have a grammatical plural in English. If you want to talk about a lot of debris—or if you want to pick it up—you have to gather it into plural *piles*.
>
> You may be wondering how a grammarian can tell that *debris* is singular instead of plural. There are two clear signs:
>
> First, *debris* always takes a singular verb: *"Debris is knee deep in the backyard."*
> Second, we always refer to it by a singular pronoun: *"The debris is knee deep. I don't know what to do with it."*
>
> *Debris* is not the only noun in English without a plural. Collective nouns that define a set of inanimate objects (*luggage, dinnerware*) are also regularly singular, as are nouns that refer to noncountable masses of substances (*bacon, lox*).
>
> As Hurricane Fran has taught us, however, *debris* would be easier to pluralize than to carry to the curb.